# Why after i Bake Light so much artifacts?

Tags: unity-game-engine, light

Its artifacted for no reason, all my objects on the Scene a Static. You can see my Lightning Settings on the scrinshot. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZJrb.jpg)

I trying to change any Lightning Settings like "Albedo Boosts" and "Indirect Intensity". But nothing happend.